# Hive: create statement is not running (Moving)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm using Hive's 13th Cloudera version.
I'm facing an issue while running any of the create statement. **Other operations like DML and drop, alter are working fine**. below is the sample statement which i'm trying to run, is there anything which I'm missing ?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PROCESS.aggregated_rspns
(
id int,
dt string,
hour string,
rspns_count bigint,
highest_rspns_count bigint
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
LOCATION '/xyz/pqr/aggregated_rspns';
```

Could someone help me resolve this issue.
Please let me know if any further information required.

Comment: Is the issue still exists? If yes, then could you provide the error/log detail.

Comment: Thanks, it is resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the well known issue of hive.
If we have below mentioned hive property true

> **hive.support.concurrency=true**
>
> **and long running insert overwrite statements running concurrently**

Above to properites creates few locks on table which is obvious as well as on database which is usability issue of hive.
To avoid this we can try to set first hive property to false which may help.
**This issue is resolved but not yet released and it includes a fix(which only applies if we are using DBTxnManager).**

Answer (score 1):

As per your answer Bector it is true, but you don't need to wait for next release you can directly add below property in your all Hqls :

> hive.support.concurrency=true;

I have tried and it is working for me, it should work for you as well.

Comment: I have already tried it and it working fine. Thanks for specifying it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE (DATABASE|SCHEMA) [IF NOT EXISTS] database_name
```

I think you need to have database created first. In your case database PROCESS needs to exist.

Comment: There is no syntax error and everything is in place which is required for query.

Answer (score 0):

Pls ensure,

1. Location is HDFS directory and not the filename.
2. Only one relevant input file is in the HDFS directory.
3. If table already exists in the PROCESS database, then no error will be thrown.
4. Even a look inside the data present in file may help.

Comment: everything is in place to execute this Query successfully, As per my understanding this is related to infrastructure which I'm trying to resolve. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Hi Partha- I would like to clear some of your confusion 1. You can create external table by providing HDFS location or even you can create table over the file also. 2. you can keep multiple input file within the HDFS directory there wont be any effect during table creation. 3.If the table exist and still you are trying to create a table with same name " You will get an error " table already exist/present"